# PHP curl POST to a remote web services call returns curl error 7 from server, but works fine from localhost

Tags: php, post, curl

I have a php script that issues a curl POST with data call to a remote web services (running on my co-worker's personal computer). It works fine and returns expected result when I run the script from localhost, but fails with curl error 7 (couldn't connect to host) and HTTP status code 0 when I upload the script on to a server (shared, not dedicated) and run it.

I tried issuing a POST to a yahoo API webservice call with the same script and it works from both server and localhost.

The webservices I mentioned is running on port 8080 (not 80), on my co-workers PC and I am accessing it through his IP address (static).

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$request =  'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/services/dataconsume';

$postargs = json_encode(array(
   'x'=> '10',
   'y'=> '20'
   ));;

$session = curl_init($request);

curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postargs);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);

$response = curl_exec($session);
echo "CURL ERROR NO : ".curl_errno($session); //returns 7
echo "<br />CURL STATUS : ".curl_getinfo($session, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //returns 0
echo "<br />CURL ERROR : ".curl_error($session); //returns "couldn't connect to host"
curl_close($session);
```

Comment: Did you try running a curl command from the server? Something like     `curl --location 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/services/dataconsume' --data x=10 --data y=20 --output test.txt`

Comment: Thanks Anirudh, I tried that and it gave the same response as my code. So I called up the host's technical support and they told me they have a rule that prevents curl requests to IP:port. Anyways, I have moved to a Virtual Server now and it works perfectly fine.